# Make a data.table out of two data.table, with the name of column[2], different

Tags: r, data.table, fread

When running the code that I present, I get the following alert:

> Column 2 ['t2'] of item 2 is missing in item 1. Use fill=TRUE to fill
> with NA (NULL for list columns), or use.names=FALSE to ignore column
> names. use.names='check' (default from v1.12.2) emits this message and
> proceeds as if use.names=FALSE for  backwards compatibility. See news
> item 5 in v1.12.2 for options to control this message.

how to correct it?

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(Smp=1:9,
                s=as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01"), by = "1 sec",length.out = 9)),
                x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6))
DT2=data.table(Smp=1:9,
               t2=as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2020-01-02"), by = "1 sec",length.out = 9)),
               x=rep(c("h","j","a"),each=3), y=c(2,5,8))
#seq(as.POSIXct("2001-01-01 04:15:20 "), by = "1 sec",length.out = 9)

tmp_dir = tempdir()
setwd(tmp_dir)
getwd()
fwrite(DT, "file2020-1.csv")
fwrite(DT2,"file2020-2.csv")

#fread("file2020-1.csv")
#fread("file2020-2.csv")

files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")#path=tmp_dir
files
rDT = rbindlist(lapply(files[c(1,2)],fread,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,check.names = T))
#2
l <- lapply(files[c(1,2)], fread,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,check.names = T)
dt <- rbindlist( l )
```

The data.table originally has 207 columns each
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because you have different column names in the two dataframes which do not match while combining into one.

You can have the same names in both the dataframes which will avoid the warning.

```
library(data.table)

cols <- c('Smp', 's','x', 'y')
rDT = rbindlist(lapply(files[c(1,2)], function(x) 
  setnames(fread(x, fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,check.names = TRUE), cols)))
```

Comment: Thanks, removed the alert!
Now the data.table originally has 207 columns each, and in column [2]
the names differ in the date and time of creation of the file. Is there a way to change the name with fread?

Comment: I am not sure if you can change a specific column in `fread`, you can pass entire vector of column names. Also with `setnames` you can change specific column names at particular position. For eg for 2nd position - `rbindlist(lapply(files[c(1,2)], function(x) 
  setnames(fread(x, fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,check.names = TRUE), 2, 's')))`

Comment: it is possible in fread to use drop = "last", to skip the last column?

Comment: `drop` takes a number of character vector of column names that need to dropped. Same for `select`. I don't think there is anything as `drop = "last"`. If you know how many columns are there in the data you can do `drop = 10` to drop 10th column.